# Manipulating ISO 2145 numbering in Javascript (1.1.1, 1.1.2 etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

How do i increment numbering using the ISO 2145 format?

For example I have a string in the format "1.2" and i like to increment to "1.3". Easy to do by converting the string to a number but i'm using ISO 2145 format which would also allow "1.2.1.1" which i would want to change to 1.2.1.2 or 1.2.2.1 for example.

I've been searching but as of yet found nothing. I'd like to be able to do things like add, subtract, or sort numbers.

Comment: do you have concrete problem? asking for libraries is ot.

Comment: I've re-worded the question

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the most complex format. With `parts = "1.2.3.4".split(".")` you get a handy array and with `parts.join(".")` you get the string back. With `parts.length` and `++` you're mostly done.